# Find the locus represented by

Tags: analytic-geometry, locus

Find the locus represented by 
$$\sqrt {(x-2)^2 + y^2} + \sqrt {(x+2)^2+y^2}=4$$

My Attempt:

Let $P(x,y)$ be any point on  the locus. If we suppose $A(2,0)$ and $B(-2,0)$ any two points on the locus then from the above equation we have:
$|PA| + |PB| = |AB|$

Answer (score 1):

As you find out we have $$|PA| + |PB| = |AB|$$

so by triangle (in)equality we see that $P$ is on the segment $AB$. So $y=0$ and $|x|\leq 2$.

Comment: ... which is essentially what the answer to the possible duplicate target says in the first sentence.

Comment: It represents a line segment $y=0$, from $x=-2$ to $x=2$ . It does not represent ellipse as $2ae=4$ and $2a=4$, the $e=1$.